# Not able to setText to inflacted View?

Tags: java, android

Below code is in OnCreate Method.

```
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nav_header_app_base, null);
    textViewUserName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewUserNameDrawer);
    textViewUserName.setText("Mr."+" "+sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.FIRST_NAME,"")+" "+sharedPreferences.getString(Constants.LAST_NAME,""));
```

Xml code is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

   <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_app_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_app_base"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_app_base_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There is textviewUserName inside nav_header_app_base.xml
I can print the textview default value using inflacted view but when I tried to set it is not reflected in view.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Show us code of `nav_header_app_base.xml`.

Comment: You did not added `view` anywhere you just created it . You have to add it to `ViewGroup`.